# Facebook electronic signature

Tags: facebook

How do I enter an electronic signature in a Facebook form that demands one before it will upload the form?

Comment: Where are you getting asked for an electronic signature?

Answer (score -1):

try [docusign](http://www.docusign.com/) an third party which will help to integrate your digital signature to any of your website it will help at facebook too